# python rank a value from list out of the list percentile using lambda

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, rank, percentile

suppose I have a list of numbers and I applied percentile on this list which returns the following dictionary

```
{100: 2004807.0, 75: 11600.0, 50: 2559.5, 25: 316.0}
```

and then I have created the following function to return the corresponding value of a percentage

```
def f(x):
    return {
        25: 316.0,
        50: 2559.5,
        75: 11600.0,
        100: 2004807.0
    }[x]
```

now the following function returns the rank of a value

```
def rank(y):
    if y <= f(25):
        return 25
    elif y <= f(50):
        return 50
    elif y <= f(75):
        return 75
    else:
        return 100
```

is this doable using python lambda ?

Comment: Do you want to convert `rank` function to `lambda`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a list from your dictionary sorted by value. This conversion is necessary because dictionaries are not ordered, unless you are using Python 3.7+.

Then use `next` and a generator expression within your `lambda`:

```
d = {100: 2004807.0, 75: 11600.0, 50: 2559.5, 25: 316.0}
d_rev = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

val = 2000
res = (lambda x: next((k for k, v in d_rev if x <= v), 100))(val)

print(res)
# 50
```

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the `f()` function, I would use `next` with a generator whilst providing a default of 100.

```
lambda y: next((x for x in [25, 50, 75] if y <= f(x)), 100)
```